# how to quotes for class value, variable text content, and variable property in jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to quotes for class value, variable text content, and variable property in jquery?

Using the following jquery code with the following variables:

```
var moveLeft = 10;
var log = [];
var strongContentText = $("#testList").text();
$("#aList").html("<input type='inputCheck' style='margin-left:"+moveLeft+"px"'>"</input>"<strong class='highLight'>"+strongContentText+"</strong><p>"+log.join(' ')+"</p>");
```

According to firebug, it says SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in this area moveLeft+"px"'>" but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have some extra quotes in there.

```
$("#aList").html("<input type='inputCheck' style='margin-left:"+moveLeft+"px'></input><strong class='highLight'>"+strongContentText+"</strong><p>"+log.join(' ')+"</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#aList").html("<input type='inputCheck' style='margin-left:"+moveLeft+"px"'>"</input>"<strong class=\'highLight\'>"'+strongContentText+'"</strong><p>'+log.join(' ')+"</p>");
```

There was some single quote and double quote problems that I tweaked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#aList").html("<input type='inputCheck' style='margin-left:" + moveLeft + "px'></input><strong class='highLight '>" + strongContentText + "</strong><p>" + log.join(' ') + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes to contain the html so you can use double quotes when specifying attributes:

```
$('#aList').html('<input type="inputCheck" style="margin-left:'+moveLeft+'px"></input><strong class="highLight">'+strongContentText+'</strong><p>'+log.join(' ')+'</p>');
```

There's no problem switching back and forth if you prefer to use one over the other. This is also helpful to avoid using escape slashes `\` in strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try now:

```
$("#aList").html("<input type='inputCheck' style='margin-left:" + moveLeft + "px'></input><strong class='highLight'>" + strongContentText + "</strong><p>" + log.join(' ')+ "</p>");
```